# Shaped image at bottom of image disappears on some resolutions

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, card

I created a curvy shape at the bottom of this image on this bootstrap card. I'm using bootstrap 5.
This works flawless on a resolution of 1400px and higher. However, on smaller devices the shape seems to disappear (causing the image to be just rectangular) and whatever I try, nothing seems to make a difference.

[image]

This is my HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
  <div class="card h-100">
    <div class="card-img">
      <img src="..." class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title">Heroine's Quest: ...</h4>
      <h5>Winner of 11 AGS Awards</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Heroine's Quest is an adventure / RPG hybrid. Like in many adventure
         games, you have a world to save, and must use your wit, guile and inven...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <a href="game-details.php" class="btn btn-ags">Learn more <span class="d-none d-sm-inline"> 
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></span> </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
.card {
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.2);
    transition: .3s;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

@media (min-width: 481px) {
    .card:hover {
        transform: scale(1.05);
        transition: .3s;
    }
}

.card .card-img {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 200px;
}

.card .card-img img {
    max-height: 199px;
    width: 100%;
}

.card .card-img:after {
    background: url(../img/home-game-highlights-shape.svg) no-repeat center bottom;
    background-size: contain;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
}

.card .card-footer {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

This is the .svg used:
https://www.rwdb.info/home-game-highlights-shape.svg

And this is the code in JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lengk6/

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying for hours and of course just after I posted I found the resolution:

I updated this:

```
.card .card-img img {
    max-height: 199px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

to this:

```
.card .card-img img {
    height: 199px;
    width: 100%;
}
```